# Making the existing codebase work with Typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-saga

I have an existing codebase which uses redux, redux-saga and react - PLAIN Javascript. Now we are planning to add Typescript to it. My queries around the same -

1. Is it possible that plain js files can c-exist with tsx code ? I think yes - I did a SIMLPE POC for the same without having redux in it.
2. Is it possible to have my existing redux and redux saga code (JS files) co-exist and integrate with new Typescript (tsx) files ? Or i will have to re-write the entire redux code.
3. If all of it is possible; please tell me guidelines on how I can go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's very easy to have typescript files and javascript files interoperate. The only thing you should need to do is add `"allowJs: true"` to the compiler options section of your `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true"
    // ... etc
  }
}
```